# Avoid lexer rules interrupting each other?

Tags: regex, antlr4

So, basically my MIPS Assembler has a few prefixes. I use "0x" and "$" for Hex numbers, "#" for decimal numbers and "%" for binary numbers. The typical way how assemblers are built.

Now, there's a little problem with the prefix "0x" interrupting with the lexer rules which match the "TEXT" rule for variable definitions. Ex.:

```
[Var1] : 0x2554D
```

Whereas Var1 is the TEXT.

My rules:

```
mips32code  : instruction+
            ;

instruction : OPCODE_ITYPE rt COMMA rs COMMA prefix imm # ITypeInstruction
            | '[' TEXT ']' ':' prefix imm               # VariableDefinition
            ;

imm         : instruction   # immformat
            | INT           # immvalue
            ;

prefix      : instruction   # prefixinst
            | VALUE         # prefixval
            ;

rs          : instruction   # rsexpr
            | REG           # rsreg
            ;

rt          : instruction   # rtexpr
            | REG           # rtreg
            ;

/* Immediate-Value Lexer */

INT         : [0-9A-Fa-f]+
            ;

/* Text for variable definition and label definition names. */
TEXT        : [a-zA-Z0-9]+
            ;

/* Prefix */
VALUE       : ('$'|'0x'|'#'|'%') 
            ;

REG
    : [rR] '0'
    | [aA] [tT]
    | [vV] [01]
    | [aA] [0-3]
    | [tT] [0-9]
    | [sS] [0-8]
    | [kK] [01]
    | [gG] [pP]
    | [sS] [pP]
    | [fF] [pP]
    | [rR] [aA]
    ;

COMMA   : ','
        ;

OPCODE_ITYPE
      : [aA] [dD] [dD] [iI] // ADDI
      | [dD] [aA] [dD] [dD] [iI] // DADDI
      | [dD] [aA] [dD] [dD] [iI] [uU] // DADDIU
      | [aA] [dD] [dD] [iI] [uU] // ADDIU
      | [oO] [rR] [iI] // ORI
      | [xX] [oO] [rR] [iI] // XORI
      | [sS] [lL] [tT] [iI] // SLTI
      | [sS] [lL] [tT] [iI] [uU] // SLTIU
      | [aA] [nN] [dD] [iI] // ANDI
      ;
```

So, the above is not working properly. It successfully matches the input like above with Var1, but instructions like these:

```
ADDIU T0, T1, 0x2544
```

Do not work, as the "0x" prefix is somehow interrupting the TEXT lexer rule. The error I receive is:

```
line 1:14 no viable alternative input 'ADDIU T0, T1, 0x2544'
```

I've tried some stuff like deleting the "+" from TEXT. Obviously, this seems to work, but then variable definitions do not match correctly anymore and just match one letter. I tried workarounds, which all ended in errors and chaos. So, I've thought that I could receive some help here.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the overlap between text and values, use a mode to provide isolation.  Easy to do here since the brackets operate as unambiguous guards.

```
LBRAKCET : '[' -> pushMode(text) ;

mode text;
TEXT     : [a-zA-Z0-9]+ ;
RBRACKET : ']' -> popMode ;
BAD_TEXT : . ;
```

Added BAD_TEXT as a catchall - gives you the option of handling some obvious errors ('var_1') in the parser.  Note, modes are only available in split lexer/parser grammars.  Also, don't use character literals in parser rules particularly in split grammars.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever 2 (or more) lexer rules match the same text, the one defined first will get precedence. That means `0x` will be matched as a `TEXT` token because that one is define before a `VALUE` token.

You will therefor also need to move rules that define keywords (`OPCODE_ITYPE`s) before `TEXT` and maybe even the `INT` rule.

Comment: I've tried this. So, now it recognizes the whole thing, except for the immediate value. Error: "line 1:14 no viable alternative at input 0x244D".

Comment: @Tetragrammaton, `0x...` should probably be a single token.

Comment: So, something like:
HEX : '0x' ;

?

Comment: @Tetragrammaton, no, `0x2544` should be one token.